# How I can describe wsdl choice element in my service class using Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover?

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I use \Zend\Soap\AutoDiscover class to generate wsdl of soap service from service class. I described type of properties in doc blocks. However, I have to describe choice element (xsd:choice) but I don't know how ?

```
  <xsd:complexType name="PaymentModeType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="mode" type="xsd:unsignedLong" />    
      <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="check" type="CheckType"/>
        <xsd:element name="balance" type="BalanceType"/>        
        <xsd:element name="money_transfer_received" type="MoneyTransferReceivedType"/>        
       </xsd:choice>
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

Thanks for your help.